# Yara in terminal

Tags: terminal

I am quite new to mac and I came across something that I think is unusual (After researching the web). When I open the terminal application, I get a "Yara:" string before the command prompt... Is it something bad? How can I get rid of this?

[image: Image description]

Comment: Please type `echo $PS1` and include this information in your question.  The command prompt string can be set by anything, this will show us where the text is coming from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default Terminal PS1 is:

```
computername:directory user$
```

Therefore, `Yara` is your computer's name.